# bind to button -None is not callable

Tags: button, kivy

i did a very simple app on kivy, i got error: "None is not callable" on the button bind line..
i dont understand why...
please your help...

my app:

```
class Search(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Search, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget((Label(text="tap the button up to start")))

        self.Start_button = Button(text='Here!', size_hint=(.5, .25), 
font_size=20)
        self.Start_button.bind(on_press=self.Start_app())
        self.add_widget(self.Start_button)

    def Start_app(self, *args):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Hey "+" what do you want to do?"))
```

please your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `on_press` should be set to a callable.
When you do like this:

```py
self.Start_button.bind(on_press=self.Start_app())
```

you actully allready called the method. And since the method returns `None`, you get the error `None is not callable`.
So you need to exclude the parantheses. Like this:

```py
self.Start_button.bind(on_press=self.Start_app)
```

Comment: @ShaharBitan you are wellcome.